# nodejs express serve-index print file creation date

Tags: node.js, express

How do you get `serve-index` to list file creation dates like in a similar way as `apache` would?

This is the code, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this, reading the serve-index README.

```
var http = require('http');
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
var app = express();
app.use('/list',serveIndex(__dirname+ '/uploads/'))
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Did you see that you can [provide your own template](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index#template)?

Comment: Or use [`dirlist`](https://github.com/jdreux/dirlist), which looks more like Apache's output.

Comment: @robertklep I did, but I think I misunderstood at first, what was written there. I checked the default template and I think I might be able to modify it to do what I want. Thanks!